# ShutDown C# Project

Tags: c#, project, shutdown

I am currently coding a program that should shutdown/restart when a button is pressed , but when i press the shutdown or restart button , the operation is done immediately without waiting for the specified time in the (datetimepicker).

Here's my code :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication8
{
    public partial class Form2 : Form
    {
        private DateTime tm;
        public Form2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (DateTime.Now.CompareTo(tm) > 0)
            {
                Sti();
                System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("shutdown", "/s");
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("your computer will shutdown shortly ....");
            }

        }
        private void Sti()
        {
            if (DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay.CompareTo(tm.TimeOfDay) > 0)
            {
                tm = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month, DateTime.Now.Day + 1, tm.Hour, tm.Minute, tm.Second);
            }
            else
            {
                tm = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month, DateTime.Now.Day, tm.Hour, tm.Minute, tm.Second);
            }

        }

        private void notifyIcon1_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            this.Show();
        }

        private void notifyIcon1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (DateTime.Now.CompareTo(tm) >= 0)
            {
                Sti();
                System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("shutdown", "/r");
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("your computer will shutdown shortly ....");
            }


        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Mohamed for starters why don't you rename your `Buttons` to same more than `Button` or Button` how about btnRestart and btnShutDown` also what is the value of the `Time` that you are passing..? `1000 = Sec`

Comment: Where and how you set `tm`?

Comment: If you aren't setting the tm, then it is going to be 1/1/0001 12:00 which will be less than the Now value every time.

Comment: Hamlet he has it in code how he is setting `tm` how could you have missed that...? LOL

Comment: DJ KRAZE : the time is sed from datetimepicker .

Comment: If you edit your code above to show the tm being set, it would clear that part of the problem up for us.  Otherwise it's hard to pick out what isn't working.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `-t` switch of `shutdown` to specify a waiting period

```
shutdown {-r|-s} -t xxx
```

where xxx is the number of seconds to wait.

Comment: I need to specify the time of shutdown or restart using the datetimepicker .

Comment: The -t needs the number of seconds to wait before shutdown.  Here's a good link on the shutdown exe: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/22718/Shutdown-Remote-Using-Shutdown-exe

Comment: @MohamedMaher How about something like this: `Process.Start("shutdown", "/r -t " + Math.Floor(tm.Value.Subtract(DateTime.Now).TotalSeconds));`